# VS30063: You are not authorized to access

Tags: tfs

I just moved my tfs 2013 to a new server and also upgraded to tfs 2015 update 1.

On my CIs, I get this weird error.

I am Project Collection Administrator, and it doesnt work
I deleted the build controller, agent and created them again but it made no difference.

I even started VS as Administrator as other so question suggested, but it didnt fix anything

TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \PowerData.Comisiones\MAIN_Comisiones:
Exception Message: One or more errors occurred. (type AggregateException)
Exception Stack Trace: at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFile(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath, Stream outputStream)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.FileContainerHelper.GetFileAsString(TfsTeamProjectCollection projectCollection, String itemPath)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.ProcessTemplate.Download(String sourceGetVersion)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildControllerWorkflowManager.PrepareRequestForBuild(WorkflowManagerActivity activity, IBuildDetail build, WorkflowRequest request, IDictionary`2 dataContext)
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Hosting.BuildWorkflowManager.TryStartWorkflow(WorkflowRequest request, WorkflowManagerActivity activity, BuildWorkflowInstance& workflowInstance, Exception& error, Boolean& syncLockTaken)
Inner Exception Details:
Exception Message: VS30063: You are not authorized to access http://myserver:8080. (type VssUnauthorizedException)
Exception Stack Trace: at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpMessageHandler.d__17.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.HttpClientExtensions.d__3.MoveNext()

Comment: Did this issue happen on an existing build definition from TFS 2013, or the new build definition created in TFS 2015? If you queue build on your build agent machine, would you see this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must make sure the service account for Team Foundation Build is a member of the Build Services group. You must also make sure that the account has read/write permissions to the temporary folders and the ASP.NET temporary folder.

Comment: can you please tell me a link to the official documentation for this. I also cant find the Build Services Group, I dont have it on Local Users and groups and I dont have it either on each Project Collection security

Answer (score 4):

Today I spent more time searching for a solution, tried to reconnect in Team Explorer -> Manage connections -> Connect to server URL and even updated vs, no use.

However, after sign-out and sign-in again in Visual Studio, it works well now. So try Sign-out & Sign-in first. If not successful, try the same after updating the visual studio, if any updates are pending.